# How to use Twilio to send customized PDF’s from Google Drive/Sheets

Tags: node.js, twilio, twilio-programmable-chat

I am having problems trying to send customized PDFs from Google Drive to users on WhatsApp using Twilio’s API.

I am using node.js and the documents are created in Google Sheets and stored in Google Drive.

```
 client.messages
  .create({
     mediaUrl:['https://drive.google.com/uc?id=INSERT_FILE_ID&export=download'],
     from: 'whatsapp:+14155238886',
     body: `It's taco time!`,
     to: 'whatsapp:+15017122661'
   })
  .then(message => console.log(message.sid));
```

I thought it would be possible to send the PDF by passing the PDF’s Drive link through MediaURL as that is what is recommended on [Twilio’s site](https://www.twilio.com/docs/whatsapp/tutorial/send-and-receive-media-messages-whatsapp-nodejs) for sending media (Images, .mp3’s and PDF’s) but when I try that it doesn’t work.

**NB: it works when I try image URL’s etc.**

I have tried sending the webContentLink of the PDF that also doesn’t work.

[example: how the pdf should look when sent](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EGJeD.jpg)

I do not want to send the user a normal link for them to leave WhatsApp.

Any help with this or any other method to achieve this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do you know how I can get the link To the raw file with Drive?  Not the preview/download link but the link for the file (eg: drive.google.com/file-name.pdf)

Answer (score 0):

Twilio will check the content-type of the file which you have been passing in the mediaUrl parameter. Twilio will reject if the content-type headers of your media attachment do not match the file extension (for example, content-type is image/jpg but the file extension is .png). It specified in the following links specifies:

1. [Twilio Troubleshooting](https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/360017961894-Sending-and-Receiving-Media-with-WhatsApp-Messaging-on-Twilio-Beta-)
2. [Twilio supported-mime-types](https://www.twilio.com/docs/whatsapp/guidance-whatsapp-media-messages#supported-mime-types)